# how to keep track of existing question?

Tags: discussion

Can someone tell how to keep track of a question that some user has posted so that i can see the answers posted to that post ?

Thanks,
Arvi.

Comment: Use the favorite star below the voting buttons. You find favorite questions in your profile page.

Comment: See http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/answer-later-feature